# Material for filling small air leaks

Tags: materials

Often beeswax is used to seal small air leaks on some musical instruments. One of the disadvantages of beeswax is that it has a melting point of around 140 degrees Fahrenheit and can therefore flow to other parts of instruments with deleterious effects. Do you know of a nontoxic substitute for beeswax with a higher melting point?

Comment: What type of leak are you sealing? Is it a connection between two elements? Is it a slip fit or threaded? Something else?

Comment: @GisMofx Just a gap between two mating surfaces. The gap is about a couple thousandths of an inch.

Comment: Is it two cylindrical surfaces? With a cylindrical gap?

Comment: @GisMofx. No. A gap between two perpendicular planes.

Comment: I’m having trouble visualizing that. Can you please provide more details? Is this for a musical instrument? Can you provide an image or sketch?

Comment: Do consider that “joining” those plates may affect or change how the music instrument sounds as it vibrates or resonates for example... So if you used hot glue instead of beeswax...

Comment: Super glue is the modern way fill small holes and imperfections. There are many types of super glue and "instant cure" accelerators for them. The "non blooming" type does not turn white after it cures, very handy in many situations.

Answer (score 2):

Beeswax is a naturally-occurring hotmelt glue, and the earliest (artificial) hotmelt glue compositions contained beeswax as one constituent. Now there are hundreds of different modern hotmelts available in which synthetic and natural waxes and resins are blended together to yield a broad range of melt temperatures and glue line strengths. I recommend you have a look at some hotmelt manufacturers' brochures & technical data; perhaps you can find a suitable beeswax replacement to test in your application.

However, note that an important quality of adhesives for musical instrument repair is the ability to undo them with heat and moisture to facilitate future repairs. The worst possible thing you can do to a clarinet, guitar, saxophone or violin is to repair it with an epoxy, cyanoacrylate or urethane glue because those will make it impossible to disassemble. So, be cautious!

Answer (score 0):

You might try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycaprolactone 
It softens at hot-water temperatures and is safe to handle. (You'll probably need to heat it a bit above that to get to fully liquid.) FDA approved for some applications, so IMHO pretty safe. This material is usually sold in granular form; some names I've seen are Polymorph, ThermoMorph and "friendly plastic."

But especially if this is a wooden instrument, be careful and if possible test on similar materials (to your instrument) *before* using it on your instrument. My concern is that it'll soak into wood and change the stiffness and thus tone.